# How can I stop thread and properly display text by Toast in thread?

Tags: java

I need solution to stop my thread and display Toast.

- Why doesn't stop my thread?
- Why doesn't my solution display "success" by Toast?

---

This is  my class **StopperThread**  where I try stop by blinker my thread.

```
public class StopperThread implements  Runnable{

    private Context context;
    private volatile boolean blinker;

    public StopperThread(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.blinker = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        try {
            while(blinker) {
                Log.e("LOG","ACTIVE");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Toast.makeText(context, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            blinker = false;
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }

    public void mystop() {
        blinker = false;

    }
}
```

---

This is my method **clickedButton**  inside the Activity where I created thread.

```
 private  void clickedButton() {
  final StopperThread stopperThread = new StopperThread(this);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(stopperThread);

    if(click)
    {
        t1.start();
        click = false;
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            stopperThread.mystop();
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      click = true;
    }
}
```

**I tried to change**

```
/*First Try*/
 final StopperThread stopperThread = new StopperThread(getApplicationContext());
```

---

```
/*Second Try*/
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            t1 = new Thread(stopperThread);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the variable click in `if(click == true)`?  (Also, `if(click)` would do the same thing if it's a boolean)

Comment: When does click get set to false?

Comment: I forgot copy variable - click. I shrunk code for readability. Click is true when user click button @MadProgrammer

Comment: try using `runOnUIThread()` in your thread to update GUI or pass `ApplicationContext` instead of `this` in `StopperThread()`.

Comment: It doesn't resolve problem. Maybe I do this wrong? @jackjay

Comment: `runOnUiThread` should be used to show the `Toast`. not to run another thread.